# How to publish a 2 dimensional array of known values

Tags: ros, array, publish

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm stuck at my program to publish a 2 dimensional array. The array kinda looks like this:

int deptharray[4][5] = {
{0, 0, 0, 0},
{0, average11, average21, average31, average41},
{0, average12, average22, average32, average42},
0, average13, average23, average33, average43},
};
I also read several posts about how to publish an int32MultiArray but unfortunately none of my attemps to publish this array of known values worked. All examples that I have seen have unknown sizes and then use the push_back function in a for loop.
I'd be really glad if you could help me.
Thank you very much

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234028/how-to-publish-a-2-dimensional-array-of-known-values/) by [beeeeck](https://answers.ros.org/users/26814/beeeeck/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-05-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If your data is always going to be a 4x5 array, you could create a custom message that contained an array of 20 integers and then do a little math to determine how to translate (row,col) access to entries in the 1D array (correct way to do this would depend on if you wanted to use column-major or row-major storage). This would work fine, but could definitely be error prone.

An alternative would be to create a custom message containing arrays of, e.g., 5 integers that would represent rows, then create another custom message that contained an array of length 4 of the first message. In C++, this would become a `std::vector< std::vector<int> >`. This would also work fine.

There is no reason you can't use the `Int32MultiArray` from std_msgs, and you certainly don't have to use `push_back`. You could just initialize a `std::vector` of length 20 for the `data` field. Here's an example:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/Int32MultiArray.h"
#include "std_msgs/MultiArrayDimension.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>

#define H (4)
#define W (5)


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "talker");
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    ros::Publisher pub = n.advertise<std_msgs::Int32MultiArray>("matrix_pub", 1);
    ros::Rate loop_rate(10);
    std_msgs::Int32MultiArray dat;
    int array[H][W] = {
        {0, 1, 2, 3, 4},
        {10, 11, 12, 13, 14},
        {20, 21, 22, 23, 24},
        {30, 31, 32, 33, 34}};

    // fill out message:
    dat.layout.dim.push_back(std_msgs::MultiArrayDimension());
    dat.layout.dim.push_back(std_msgs::MultiArrayDimension());
    dat.layout.dim[0].label = "height";
    dat.layout.dim[1].label = "width";
    dat.layout.dim[0].size = H;
    dat.layout.dim[1].size = W;
    dat.layout.dim[0].stride = H*W;
    dat.layout.dim[1].stride = W;
    dat.layout.data_offset = 0;
    std::vector<int> vec(W*H, 0);
    for (int i=0; i<H; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<W; j++)
            vec[i*W + j] = array[i][j];
    dat.data = vec;

    while (ros::ok())
    {
        pub.publish(dat);
        loop_rate.sleep();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2016-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aaditya_saraiya](https://answers.ros.org/users/31473/aaditya_saraiya/) on 2017-10-23**:
Hey,  there are two consecutive same lines in the code. Is this done for a reason? Sorry I am not able to understand why that same line is run twice.
dat.layout.dim.push_back(std_msgs::MultiArrayDimension());
dat.layout.dim.push_back(std_msgs::MultiArrayDimension());

Thanks in advance.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2017-10-23**:
It's because this is a two-dimensional array. So the `dat.layout.dim` array of `std_msgs/MultiArrayDimension` has one entry for the "width" channel,  and one entry for the "height" channel. That's why I access `dat.layout.dim[0]` and `dat.layout.dim[1]`. The array starts empty, and I `push_back` 2x

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2017-10-23**:
Probably the best example to read is the example provided in comments in the [std_msgs/MultiArrayLayout message definition.](http://docs.ros.org/api/std_msgs/html/msg/MultiArrayLayout.html)

**Comment by [aaditya_saraiya](https://answers.ros.org/users/31473/aaditya_saraiya/) on 2017-10-26**:
Thank you so much @jarvisschultz for confirming. I had a similar thought but was asking just for the sake of correctness.

**Comment by [aaditya_saraiya](https://answers.ros.org/users/31473/aaditya_saraiya/) on 2017-10-26**:
@jarvisschulz Hey. tested it today with few minor changes. Works perfectly. Thanks again

**Comment by [dual-swordsman](https://answers.ros.org/users/40035/dual-swordsman/) on 2019-06-12**:
What is stride for? From my reading, it is seems that parameter use when image is involved. What I'm not sending image metadata? Is this parameter must be define or we can skip it if we don't use it?
@jarvisschultz

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2019-06-12**:
@ZazAa also posted on a [public gist I made](https://gist.github.com/jarvisschultz/7a886ed2714fac9f5226) to answer another question. Those interested in this comment discussion may also find that communication thread of interest.